# Why the footer doesn't appear on IE10 and IE9?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

My page works fine on IE11 and on Google Chrome, but when I try to open it using IE10 and IE9, It doesn't appear, it looks like it has been cut, and the scrolling bar doesn't appear as well, If someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong, I'd be glad.

Thanks in advance.

P.S.: Sorry for my ugly code

```js
$(function(){
    
 //Internet Explorer | if | 9-11
   function isIE () {
   var myNav = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    return (myNav.indexOf('msie') != -1) ? parseInt(myNav.split('msie')[1]) : false;
 } 
 var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
 
 if (isIE () == 9) {
  document.getElementById("rightcorner").style.marginTop = "3px";
                document.getElementById("leftcorner").style.marginTop = "3px";
  document.getElementById("leftcorner").style.height = "21px";
  document.getElementById("rightcorner").style.height = "21px";
  document.getElementsByClassName("th_line")[0].style.height = "21px";
  document.getElementById("thead").style.marginTop = "-29px";
  document.getElementById("thead").style.marginLeft = "16px"; 
  document.getElementById("thead").style.marginRight = "8px";
  document.getElementById("cabecaixa").style.height = "20px";
  
  

 } else if (isIE () == 10){
  document.getElementById("rightcorner").style.marginTop = "3px";
         document.getElementById("leftcorner").style.marginTop = "3px";
  document.getElementById("leftcorner").style.height = "21px";
  document.getElementById("rightcorner").style.height = "21px";
  document.getElementsByClassName("th_line")[0].style.height = "19px";
  document.getElementById("thead").style.marginTop = "-29px";
  document.getElementById("thead").style.marginLeft = "14px";
  document.getElementById("thead").style.marginRight = "22px";
  document.getElementById("cabecaixa").style.height = "20px";

 } else if (ua.indexOf("Trident/7.0") > 0) {
  document.getElementById("rightcorner").style.marginTop = "3px";
         document.getElementById("leftcorner").style.marginTop = "3px";
  document.getElementById("leftcorner").style.height = "21px";
  document.getElementById("rightcorner").style.height = "21px";
  document.getElementsByClassName("th_line")[0].style.height = "19px";
  document.getElementById("thead").style.marginTop = "-29px";
  document.getElementById("thead").style.marginLeft = "14px";
  document.getElementById("thead").style.marginRight = "21px";
  document.getElementById("cabecaixa").style.height = "16px";
  $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");

 }else{
  document.getElementById("rightcorner").style.marginTop = "3px";
         document.getElementById("leftcorner").style.marginTop = "3px";
  document.getElementById("leftcorner").style.height = "21px";
  document.getElementById("rightcorner").style.height = "21px";
  document.getElementsByClassName("th_line")[0].style.height = "19.5px";
  document.getElementById("thead").style.marginTop = "-29px";
  document.getElementById("thead").style.marginLeft = "14px";
  document.getElementById("thead").style.marginRight = "22px";
  document.getElementById("cabecaixa").style.height = "20px";
  $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
 }
 //Internet Explorer | if | 9-11
  
  
    $( "#btfirst" ).button({
      icons: {
        primary: "ui-icon-seek-first"
      },
      text: false
    });
    $("#btfirst").css({'height': '1.2em','margin':'1px'});

    $( "#btprev" ).button({
      icons: {
        primary: "ui-icon-seek-prev"
      },
      text: false
    });
    $("#btprev").css({'height': '1.2em','margin':'1px'});


    $( "#btnext" ).button({
      icons: {
        primary: "ui-icon-seek-next"
      },
      text: false
    });
    $("#btnext").css({'height': '1.2em','margin':'1px'});


    $( "#btlast" ).button({
      icons: {
        primary: "ui-icon-seek-end"
      },
      text: false
    });
    $("#btlast").css({'height': '1.2em','margin':'1px'});

   
});
```

```css
 
@font-face
{
 font-family: 'agroverdanab';
 src: url('./fonts/agroverdanab.eot');
 src: local('agroverdanab'), url('./fonts/agroverdanab.ttf') format('truetype');


 font-family: 'agroverdana';
 src: url('./fonts/agroverdana.eot');
 src: local('agroverdana'), url('./fonts/agroverdana.ttf') format('truetype');
}

html,body{height:99.3%;margin:0;padding:2px}

#header{border-bottom:1px solid #79B7E7; height:3%;font-family:"agroverdanab";font-size:13px;font-weight:600; margin-bottom:4px; margin-top:2px}
#navdata{}
#navbar{border-bottom:solid 1px #79B7E7;padding:2px}
#navbutton{float:right;}
#msgbar{border:solid 1px #79B7E7;border-top:solid 1px #79B7E7; height:3%; }
#footer{border-top:0;height:5%;position:relative;} //<--THE FOOTER :)

table{table-layout:fixed;width:100%;height:60%}
table thead tr{top:expression(offsetParent.scrollTop -2);background-color:#9BC2E6;font-family:"agroverdana";font-size:12px;overflow-y:hidden}
table tbody tr.color{background-color:#DDEBF7;font-family:"agroverdana";font-size:12px}
table tbody tr{background-color:#FFFFFF;font-family:"agroverdana";font-size:12px;border:0}

body {overflow-y: hidden}

.colgroup1{height: 1px; background-color:#9BC2E6;font-family:"agroverdana";font-size:12px;text-align: center;}
  
.th_line{margin-left:-10px; width: 300em;}
  
#thead{position:fixed}
  
#table_model{ height: 10px}  
  
#rightcorner{width: 30px; right: 7px; margin-left: -2px; background-color: #9BC2E6; position:fixed}
#leftcorner{width: 30px; left: 7px; margin-right: -2px; background-color: #9BC2E6; position:fixed}

#div_main{overflow: hidden; height:100%;display:flex;flex-direction:column; border:1px solid #79B7E7}
  
#content{height:100%;overflow-y: auto;overflow-x: hidden;border-bottom: 30px;position: relative;flex:1}

#cabecaixa{margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; margin-right: -2px; margin-left: -3px; border-top: 1px solid #79B7E7}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
<title>Central de Controle da Engenharia</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>

<div id="div_main">
 <header id="header" style="text-align:center;">Central de Controle da Engenharia</header>

 <header id="navbar">
  <input type="text" id="vpad-pesq">
  <select>
   <option>Código</option>
   <option>Nome</option>
  </select>
  
      <div id="navbutton">
   <button id="btfirst"></button>
   <button id="btprev"></button>
   <button id="btnext"></button>
   <button id="btlast"></button>
   </div>
      
      <div id="cabecaixa">
        <div id="rightcorner"></div>
         <div id="leftcorner"></div>
      </div>
 
    </header>
  
    <section id="content">
     <div id="navdata"> 
      <table style="overflow-y:visible">
              
              <thead id="thead">
         <tr>
                      <th class="th_line">Código</th>
               <th class="th_line">Descrição</th>
    <th class="th_line">Descrição</th>
     <th class="th_line">Descrição</th>
           
    

      </tr>
          </thead>
                
    <tbody>
                    <tr class="color"><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td><td>9.99</td><td>9.99</td><td>9.99</td></tr>
                    <tr class="color"><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr><td>002</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr class="color"><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr class="color"><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr class="color"><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr class="color"><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr class="color"><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr class="color"><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr class="color"><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr class="color"><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr class="color"><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr class="color"><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr class="color"><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr class="color"><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr class="color"><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr class="color"><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr class="color"><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr class="color"><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr class="color"><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr class="color"><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr class="color"><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr><td>003</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     
    </tbody>
   </table>
   
  </div>
 </section>
 
 <section id="msgbar"></section>
 <footer id="footer">Rodapé</footer>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to include this in your CSS

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Have a look at [HTML5 Shim.](https://github.com/afarkas/html5shiv)

Comment: May you explain me why? :)

Comment: HTML5shim is great but don't use the googlecode version; it will be disappearing https://code.google.com/hosting/moved?project=html5shim, download from https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv instead and serve it from a local folder, it is only a small file.